Equivalence of Definitions of Complemented Subspaces
I am seeking clarification on the equivalence of two definitions of a complemented subspace in functional analysis.
$\textbf{Definition 1:}$
A closed subspace $W$ of a Banach space $V$ is said to be complemented if there exists another closed subspace $W'$ such that $V = W \oplus W'$ and $W \cap W' = \{0\}$.
$\textbf{Definition 2:}$
A closed subspace $W$ of a Banach space $V$ is said to be complemented if there exists a bounded linear projection $P: V \rightarrow W$.
I would like to prove the equivalence of these two definitions. My Ansatz is
$\textbf{Definition 1 implies Definition 2:}$
Assume Definition 1 holds. Let $W'$ be the closed subspace complement to $W$ as defined in Definition 1. Define a bounded linear projection $P: V \rightarrow W$ as follows: for any $v \in V$, express $v$ uniquely as $v = w + w'$ with $w \in W$ and $w' \in W'$, then define $P(v) = w$.
$\textbf{Definition 2 implies Definition 1:}$
This can be seen as $V = \text{im}(P) \oplus \ker(P) = W \oplus W'$.
I am puzzling if this is already the proof for the equivalence because it seems to easy. In a text from LMU München I saw that one needs to use Zorns Lemma for $\textbf{Definition 1 implies Definition 2:}$, so I think I might missing something essential.

In your proof, why is $P$ bounded?

@MartinArgerami it seems I might have been too quick here and did a stupid mistake. My P doesn't seem to be continuous, or is there a way to salvage it?

@MartinArgerami I am still thinking how Zorn could help there. Maybe you can define P on every basis vector of V and map it to a basis vector of W. Such a construction could lead to troubles when the basis isnt finite anymore (like in functional analysis in most of the cases). So is this where Zorn is applied? I am still puzzling if this is maybe just nonsense.

I don't think you need Zorn, but you need some theory. The usual argument uses the Open Mapping Theorem.

@MartinArgerami I apologize, but I cant follow the argument of the Open Mapping Theorem. How is it helpful to show that P is an open map.

I have put the explanation into an answer.

I don't think that as much as Zorn is needed, but some theory is. Usually it's the Open Mapping Theorem. What one does is to consider the identity map $\iota:X\to X$, where one considers the usual norm on the codomain, and $\|w+w'\|_d=\|w\|+\|w'\|$ on the domain. This map is obviously bijective, and it's bounded because
$$
\|\iota(x)\|=\|w+w'\|\leq\|w\|+\|w'\|=\|x\|_d.
$$
The Open Mapping Theorem then guarantees that $\iota$ is invertible. This means that there exists $c>0$ such that
$$
\|w\|+\|w'\|\leq c\|w+w'\|. 
$$
This gives you
$$
\|Px\|=\|w\|\leq\|w\|+\|w'\|\leq c\|x\|, 
$$
and $P$ is bounded.

Proof that the internal direct sum is isomorphic (as Banach spaces) with the external direct sum.
Let $X=V+W$, with $V,W$ closed subspaces and $V\cap W=\{0\}$. Let $Y=V\oplus W$, with the norm $\|(v,w)\|_d=\|v\|+\|w\|$. Let $\iota:Y\to X$ be the map $(v,w)\longmapsto v+w$. This map is obviously bijective (its inverse is $v+w\longmapsto (v,w)$, which is well-defined because $X$ is the direct sum of $V,W$). And it is bounded because
$$
\|\iota(v,w)\|=\|v+w\|\leq\|v\|+\|w\|=\|(v,w)\|_d. 
$$
The Open Mapping Theorem then guarantees that $\iota$ is invertible. That is, $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic as Banach spaces.

oh wow thats a wonderful application of the Open Mapping Theorem. Thank you for showing me this.

Glad I could help!

I have one more question. How do we show that X with the new defined norm is still a Banach Space. Because for me this looks like we have shown that the norms are equivalent what we would need that both are Banach spaces to apply the open mapping theorem. @MartinArgerami

Very good point. It is trivial because of the way the new norm is defined. In the new norm, for a sequence ${w_n+w_n'}$ to be Cauchy means that ${w_n}$ and ${w_n'}$ are Cauchy. So $X$ with the $|\cdot|_d$ norm is Banach as long as $X$ is Banach and $W,W'$ are closed.

ok, I am a bit confused now by the different existing definitions on Complemented Subspace. If we start with the linear bounded Projection then because of continuity $W$ (which is $im(P)$) and $W'$ (which is $ker(P)$) are closed right? I also saw "$M$ is closed in $X$, there exists another closed subspace $N \subseteq X$, and $S$ is an isomorphism from the abstract direct sum $M \oplus N$ to $X$." So there one requires additionaly that this isomorphism exists. But didnt we show that we dont need that? @MartinArgerami

The image of $P$ is closed because $P$ is a bounded projection. As for the direct sum, you need to pay attention to the difference between an internal and an external direct sum. In my answer, with the choice of $|\cdot|_d$  I'm modelling the external direct sum inside $X$.

yes ok I understand. But arent the internal direct sum and the external direct sum always isomorph as shown here: https://www.math.ncku.edu.tw/~fjmliou/advcal/sumvspace.pdf

Yes. But not because of what you linked, that does not consider topology. That an internal direct sum of closed subspaces of a Banach space is isomorphic to the external direct sum is a non-trivial result, which is precisely what I prove in my answer.

I am sorry but it seems like you lost me. How did you show in the answer that the external direct sum and interanl are isomorphic? I thought the answer showed the existence of the bounded projection or what did I mess up here.

The existence of $P$ are the last three lines. The rest of the answer consists of proving that the internal sum is isomorphic to the external sum (in the sense of a linear bijective bicontinuous map).

why dont we have to work with the external direct sum instead of X in the mapping then.

It doesn't make a difference. But you wrote your question using the internal direct sum, so I answered using the internal direct sum. And there is nothing to gain by using the external direct sum, it just complicates notation, and the argument is exactly the same.

because they are isomorph, right? but I still dont see the proof for that in the answer. I am so sorry

Please see the edit.
